# Size VBA ActiveX textbox with a cell

Tags: vba, excel-2010, activex

I am currently creating a small user interface. Part of it is a text entry, so I want to use multiple ActiveX texboxes, which should merge with/on top of specific cells.

I struggle finding a solution for that problem and with editing the boxes correctly.

Help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

edit:
I found this code, but it does not seem to work:

```
With Sheets("name of the sheet")
  Set Rng = .Range(.TextBox1.LinkedCell) ' Linked that cell in activebox properties

 .TextBox1.Width = Rng.Width
 .TextBox1.Height = Rng.Height
 End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As OLEObject

Set a = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("Textbox1")

a.Width = Range(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(1).Object.Value).Width
```

Hope this helps.  Here is the MS link that will explain more

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840244.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I still struggle, but I will focus on the OLEO objects and maybe it will work